# Where do I put the ".paginate" call on this filtered object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I'd like to paginate the appointments listed on my index page, but i'm not sure where to put the paginate message. Here's how I've implemented my index method in the controller:

```
def index
    if !current_user.nil?
      filter = []
      @my_apps = Appointment.joins(:client).where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)

      if !params[:paid].blank?
        paid = params[:paid]
        filter << ["copay_received = '#{paid.to_s}'"]
      end

      if !params[:effective_on].blank?
        junk = params[:effective_on]
        filter << ["clients.effective_on >= '#{junk.to_s}'"]
      end 

      @unpaids = @my_apps.where(filter.join(" AND "))  
    else
      redirect_to '/signin'
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried appending `.paginate(page: params[:page])` to the `Appointment` object, after the where clause and after the where clause of `@my_apps` but no luck.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it after you set `@my_apps`.

For instance...

```
@my_apps = Appointment.joins(:client).where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)
@my_apps = @my_apps.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

I ran into the same problem as you, but this fixed my issue with pagination.